# Image resize in Swift only works properly in some iPhone models

Tags: swift, image

I have an ImageView on my Storyboard layout and I put some images over this ImageView.
To maintain the proportion of the image I created a code to calculate the image scale.

```
static func getImageScale(_ myImage:UIImageView) -> (width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat)  {
    let imageViewHeight = myImage.bounds.height
    let imageViewWidth = myImage.bounds.width
    
    let imageSize = myImage.image!.size
    
    let myScaledImageHeight = imageViewHeight / imageSize.height
    let myScaledImageWidth = imageViewWidth / imageSize.width
    
    return (width: myScaledImageWidth, height: myScaledImageHeight)
}
```

This is how I use the code above:

```
ImageMarcasHelper.addScaledImageToScreenWithoutMovement(imageStringName: nome_imagem, scaledImageWidth: percentImageScale.width, scaledImageHeigth: percentImageScale.height, view: view)
```

Finally, I call this:

```
static func addScaledImageToScreenWithoutMovement(imageStringName imageNameString:String, scaledImageWidth:CGFloat, scaledImageHeigth:CGFloat, view:UIView) {
    var xFinal = 0
    var scaledImageWidthMultiplied:CGFloat = 0.0
    
    let vc: UIViewController = view.parentViewController!
    let vc_name = type(of: vc)
    
    let image = UIImage(named: imageNameString)
    print(image!)
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
    imageView.isAccessibilityElement = true
    imageView.restorationIdentifier = imageNameString
    
    if vc_name == ResenhaMarcasCabecaController.classForCoder() ||
       vc_name == ResenhaMarcasMembrosPosterioresController.classForCoder() {
        print("ResenhaMarcasCabecaController view used")
        xFinal = Int((image?.size.width)!/1.9)
        scaledImageWidthMultiplied = (image?.size.width)! * 1
    } else {
        // identifica todas as outras views como ResenhaMarcasFocinhoController ou ResenhaMarcasPescocoController ou ResenhaMarcasMembrosAnterioresController
        print("viewcontroller genenrica usada")
        xFinal = 0
        scaledImageWidthMultiplied = (image?.size.width)! * scaledImageWidth
    }
    
    imageView.frame = CGRect(
        x: xFinal,
        y: 0,
        width:  Int( scaledImageWidthMultiplied ),
        height: Int( (image?.size.height)! * scaledImageHeigth )
    )
    view.addSubview(imageView)
}
```

On some iPhone models the image resize works perfectly, but on other models it is not calculated correctly.

Check below the images from an iPhone 8 and an iPhone 8 Plus

[image: Text]

The red image on the left side is centered, but on the right side the red image is NOT centered.

How can I fix that? There is another code that can I use to fix it or do I need to adapt something on my code?

Or maybe another solution, there is any way to detect the type of screen size or dimension? The same problem happens with iPhone 11 Max and iPhone Max Pro.

The red image is centered on iPhone 11 Max, but is NOT centered on iPhone Max Pro.

--- EDIT ---

```
@IBOutlet weak var imagemPrincipalCabeca:UIImageView!
```

I have an IBOutlet that contains the ImageView that I created using Storyboard with AutoLayout and I use the image inside this ImageView to get the scale to apply to other images.

This is the code that I use to get and apply the scale from the IBOutlet that is assigned to the ImageView

```
let percentImageScale = ImageMarcasHelper.getImageScale(imagemPrincipalCabeca)

ImageMarcasHelper.addScaledImageToScreenWithoutMovement(
imageStringName: nome_imagem, 
scaledImageWidth: percentImageScale.width, 
scaledImageHeigth: percentImageScale.height, 
view: view)
```

Comment: The most important thing (to me) that is missing is *when* your scaling computation is happening in the view or view controller lifecycle. Another important thing is, are you using auto layout at all?

Comment: @dfd I edit the answer and added the code that I use to get and apply the scaling computation. I use AutoLayout when I created the ImageView on the Storyboard. I use an IBOutlet to get this ImageView and use the image inside of it to get the scale that this image is adjusted. Then I add new ImageView inside over the this Main ImageView and scale the image based on the previous image from the Main ImageView.

Comment: See any of https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A341994+is%3Aa+code%3AviewDidLoad+too+soon+size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out what is the problem.

All calculations are done inside the "viewDidLoad" method. Inside this method, the calculations are not correct because the view still does't know the correct size of the subviews(the container view)

I change all the calculations to be made inside the "viewWillAppear" method. This way I was able to get the correct screen width and height for the subview.